# How can I convert decimal? to decimal

Tags: c#, .net, decimal, type-conversion, nullable

may be it is a simple question but I'm try all of conversion method! and it still has error!
would you help me?

decimal? (nullable decimal) to decimal

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try using the `??` operator:

```
decimal? value=12;
decimal value2=value??0;
```

0 is the value you want when the `decimal?` is null.

Answer (score 120):

There's plenty of options...

```
decimal? x = ...

decimal a = (decimal)x; // works; throws if x was null
decimal b = x ?? 123M; // works; defaults to 123M if x was null
decimal c = x.Value; // works; throws if x was null
decimal d = x.GetValueOrDefault(); // works; defaults to 0M if x was null
decimal e = x.GetValueOrDefault(123M); // works; defaults to 123M if x was null
object o = x; // this is not the ideal usage!
decimal f = (decimal)o; // works; throws if x was null; boxes otherwise
```

Comment: +1. I prefer `GetValueOrDefault`, because it does not depend on C# syntax and as such, can be used in VB.NET as well. It is also easily adjustable, in case default value of the type does not work for you.

Comment: what about Convert.ToDecimal(); ? can i use it for decimal to decimal coversion?

Comment: @NullReference what would it mean to do "decimal to decimal" conversion? There is [decimal Convert.ToDecimal(decimal)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xhfcwt6(v=vs.110).aspx), but that **literally** just returns the input value

Answer (score 15):

You don't need to *convert* a nullable type to obtain its value.

You simply take advantage of the [`HasValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx) and [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6.aspx) properties exposed by `Nullable<T>`.

For example:

```
Decimal? largeValue = 5830.25M;

if (largeValue.HasValue)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The value of largeNumber is {0:C}.", largeValue.Value);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("The value of largeNumber is not defined.");
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) in C# 2.0 or later as a shortcut.

Answer (score 5):

It depends what you want to do if the `decimal?` is `null`, since a `decimal` can't be `null`. If you want to default that to 0, you can use this code (using the *null coalescing operator*):

```
decimal? nullabledecimal = 12;

decimal myDecimal = nullabledecimal ?? 0;
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use.

`decimal? v = 2;`

decimal v2 = Convert.ToDecimal(v);

If the value is null (v), it will be converted to 0.

Comment: I thought that Convert.ToDecimal() was string representations, not for converting nullable decimal to decimal. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k6z9cdw(v=vs.110).aspx