# Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal?' to 'decimal'

Tags: c#

The `PriceOffer` property is nullable of decimal

```
 List<TopRated> TopRated = (from review in db.ProductReviews
                            group review by review.ProductID into product
                            select new TopRated
                            {
                              ProductName = product.Select(p => p.Products.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                              Price = product.Select(p => p.Products.Price).FirstOrDefault(),
                              PriceOffer = product.Select(p => p.Products.PriceOffer).FirstOrDefault(),
                              ProductId = product.Key,
                              AverageRating = product.Average(p => p.Rating)
                            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Is the `PriceOffer` property on `TopRated` also `decimal?`?

Comment: The error message seems to be pretty clear, right?

Comment: @DaveZych It now is. Do you mind posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 12):

To convert from `decimal?` to `decimal`, try `Value`:

```
decimal? d = 0;
decimal d1 = d.Value;
```

As **@Tim** commented, it throws exception if `decimal?` has no value.

Depending on your logic, you may try something like

```
decimal d1 = d.HasValue? d.Value: 0;
```

or just

```
decimal d2 = d ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this product.Select(p => p.Products.PriceOffer).FirstOrDefault() returns a decimal type. You can't type decimal to nullable decimal.

Here you can fin examples of such a casting: 
[How can I convert decimal? to decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871994/how-can-i-convert-decimal-to-decimal)

Comment: "You can't type decimal to nullable decimal." - it is the other way around - as the error message indicates.